# Embedded react router does not display components

Tags: reactjs

Using `react-router-dom`, components are not displaying inside my embedded router.

Made sure all of the spellings were correct, the components load fine without the router.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import { Router, Route, Switch } from 'react-router-dom'
import Constants from '../helpers/Constants'
import Header from "./Header";
import SideBar from "./SideBar";
import Candidate from "./Candidate";
import Settings from "./Settings";

export default class Base extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <Header/>
                <SideBar/>
                <div id="app-body">
                    <Switch>
                        <Route component={Candidate} exact path="/#candidates"/>
                        <Route component={Settings} exact path="/#settings"/>
                    </Switch>
                </div>
            </div>
        )}
}
```

nothing is visible

Comment: Where is your base `Router`?

Comment: You are importing Router which you probably shouldn’t do. Instead import BrowserRouter or HashRouter and use that. That being said, where are you using this imported Router currently?

Comment: Check how to setup routing- https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/example/basic